# Cannot move uploaded file

Tags: php, linux, web, backend

I've been trying to upload a file to my website. The name is stored in my database. I tried all kinds of path notations:

../images/products, images/products, /var/www/html/images/products

But none seem to work. And yes, it is being submitted with POST. I've been thinking that perhaps PHP doesn't have the permissions to write to that location?

Here you can see my code:

```
$imageName = $image['name'];
        $imageTmp = $image['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $image['size'];
        $imgError = $image['error'];

        $imgExt = explode('.',$imageName);
        $imgActualExt = strtolower(end($imgExt));

        $allowedExt = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

        if(in_array($imgActualExt, $allowedExt))
        {
            if($imgError === 0)
            {
                if($imgSize <= 5000000) #If imgSize is smaller then or equal to 5MB
                {
                    $imageNewName = uniqid('', true) . "." . $imgActualExt;
                    $imageDest = "../images/products/" . $imageNewName;
                    if(move_uploaded_file($imageTmp,$imageDest))
                    {
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO Products (name, stock, price, image_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
                        {
                            header("Location: ../dashboard.php?error=sqlerror1");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $name, $stock, $price, $imageNewName);
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                            header("Location: ../dashboard.php?successWithImage=".$imageTmp);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: ../dashboard.php?error=CouldNotMove");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: ../dashboard.php?error=Size=".$imgSize);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: ../dashboard.php?error=Error:" . $imgError);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: ../dashboard.php?error=FileTypeNotAllowed");
        }
```

Comment: First of all your code has a directory traversal security breach here. Secondly use mime_content_type to check the file extension and don't trust users input.I don't see any issues why this shall not work create logs and just check what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the directory and also check the permissions.
Try this

```
$imageNewName = uniqid('', true) . "." . $imgActualExt;
/////////
mkdir("hi");
$imageDest = "hi/" . $imageNewName;
/////////
if(move_uploaded_file($imageTmp,$imageDest))
```

Comment: And test with full path of file and destination